# How do I make my Div Box Slide in and out of the Body smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div box move in and out of the body element once I click a button. So far, my code can only make the div box slide in smoothly but when sliding out, it just immediately disappear.

I've put the code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eau7fn1x/1/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="nav-button" type="button" onclick="showNav(this)">=</button>
    <span class="header">
      <h1 class="title">Title here</h1>
    </span>
    <div id="list-of-nav">
      <p>Navigation</p>
    </div>
    <script src="src/js/index.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```js
var navShowCount = 0;
var speed = 10;

function showNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("list-of-nav");
  if (navShowCount % 2 == 0) {
    nav.style.left = "-300px";
    nav.style.display = "inline";
    let navLeftPos = nav.offsetLeft;
    nav.style.left = (navLeftPos + 300) + 'px';
  } else {
    nav.style.left = "0px"; //problem around here?
    let navLeftPos = nav.offsetLeft;
    nav.style.left = (navLeftPos - 150) + 'px';
    nav.style.display = "none";
  }
  navShowCount++;
}
```

Expecting my div box to slide in and out smoothly, but it only applies for it sliding in, not out.

I've tried tinkering with the JavaScript code but still can't make it slide out smoothly, please help

Comment: Cause `display` does not have transition effect.

Comment: @Shuo ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
var navShowCount = 0;
var speed = 10;

function showNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("list-of-nav");
  if (navShowCount % 2 == 0) {
    nav.style.left = "-300px";
    nav.style.display = "inline";
    let navLeftPos = nav.offsetLeft;
    nav.style.left = (navLeftPos + 300) + 'px';
  } else {
    nav.style.left = "-300px";
    let navLeftPos = nav.offsetLeft;
  }
  navShowCount++;
}
```

```css
* {
  color: whitesmoke;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  margin: 12px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-button {
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  padding: 20px 20px;
  float: left;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  background-color: purple;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
}

#list-of-nav {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -300px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 300px;
  transition: left 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
}

#list-of-nav * {
  color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="nav-button" type="button" onclick="showNav(this)">=</button>
    <span class="header">
      <h1 class="title">Title here</h1>
    </span>
    <div id="list-of-nav">
      <p>Navigation</p>
    </div>
    <script src="src/js/index.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```